# Selecting and replacing a formatted text in UWP RichEditBox with new text is taking the old formatting , i need new text with default formatting

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Assume I am changing the foreground color of the first five letters to green ,and the default foreground color is black for the REB .

```
ITextRange range = Editor.Document.GetRange(0, 4);
range.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Green;
```

Now if I select this text and replace with a single word , I need new text in black .But REB is retaining the old formatting for that text range and writes in green .

Comment: When you input the new text in that range, it will inherit its surrounding format, so the new text will automatically display as Green. However, currently there is no api to replace the formatted text with new text in black directly.

Comment: any workaround to achieve this ? stuck with this poblem for a long time

Comment: Maybe you could try to subscribe the SelectionChanging event and detect if its SelectionStart and SelectionLength are the same as your range, then change the format of text you add manually.